# Ruby dynamically naming arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, dynamic

I want to iterate through a number of arrays and want to dynamically name them from an array of names. Something like this, replace `name` with the elements from the `names array`...

```
names=[a, b, c]
names.each{|name|
name_array1=[]
name_array2=[]
name_array[0][0].each{|i|                           
    if i>0
        name_array1.push([i])
    end
    if i<0
        name_array2.push([i])
    end
  }
}
```

basically creating the arrays `a_array1`, `a_array2`, `a_array[0][0]`, `b_array1`, `b_array2`, `b_array[0][0]`, `c_array1`, `c_array2`, `c_array[0][0]`

Is this even possible?

Comment: @pst, no not familiar with hashes... just starting to get a hang of arrays.

Comment: @pst Note that you can’t have dynamic local variable names in Ruby 1.9 (though you can in earlier versions), only instance and class variables.

Comment: @pst, so if I understand correctly this is not doable and I must use hashes if I want to do something similiar?

Comment: @pst, so instead of renaming the arrays with different names, I should increment the array names like a_array1, b_array1, c_array1... a_array2, b_array2, c_array2... incrementing the numeric value and not changing the name? Sorry if my post is confusing, but as you can probably tell that's exactly what I am right now is confused :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby does not support dynamic local variable names<sup>1</sup>.

However, this can be easily represented using a [Hash](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm). A Hash maps a Key to a Value and, in this case, the Key represents a "name" and the Value is the Array:

```
# use Symbols for names, although Strings would work too
names = [:a, :b, :c]

# create a new hash
my_arrays = {}

# add some arrays to our hash
names.each_with_index { |name, index|
   array = [index] * (index + 1)
   my_arrays[name] = array
}

# see what we have
puts my_arrays

# access "by name"
puts my_arrays[:b]
```

(There are ways to write the above without side-effects, but this should be a start.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Dynamic instance/class variable names are a different story, but are best left as an "advanced topic" for now and are *not applicable* to the current task. In the past (Ruby 1.8.x), `eval` could be used to alter local variable bindings, but this was never a "good" approach and [does not work](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/155673) in newer versions.

Comment: Thank you! Learn something new everyday :)